# Failed to determine supertype of Datetime

Tags: python-polars

```
Polars: 0.16.2
Python: 3.11.1
Windows 10
```

Attempting to filter a column using a time range via `.is_between()`

Couldn't find anything on StackOverflow, but found (maybe?) something similar in the github issues (but it's been solved): https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5236

To reproduce

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import time

df = pl.date_range(low=datetime(2023, 2, 7), high=datetime(2023, 2, 8), interval="30m", name="date").to_frame()

# Attempt to filter by time
df.filter(
    pl.col('date').is_between(time(9, 30), time(14, 30))
)
```

Traceback:

```
PanicException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 1
----> 1 df.filter(
      2     pl.col('date').is_between(time(9, 30, 0, 0), time(14, 30, 0, 0))
      3 )

File d:\My_Path\venv\Lib\site-packages\polars\internals\dataframe\frame.py:2747, in DataFrame.filter(self, predicate)
   2741 if _check_for_numpy(predicate) and isinstance(predicate, np.ndarray):
   2742     predicate = pli.Series(predicate)
   2744 return (
   2745     self.lazy()
   2746     .filter(predicate)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
-> 2747     .collect(no_optimization=True)
   2748 )

File d:\My_Path\venv\Lib\site-packages\polars\internals\lazyframe\frame.py:1146, in LazyFrame.collect(self, type_coercion, predicate_pushdown, projection_pushdown, simplify_expression, no_optimization, slice_pushdown, common_subplan_elimination, streaming)
   1135     common_subplan_elimination = False
   1137 ldf = self._ldf.optimization_toggle(
   1138     type_coercion,
   1139     predicate_pushdown,
   (...)
   1144     streaming,
   1145 )
-> 1146 return pli.wrap_df(ldf.collect())

PanicException: cannot coerce datatypes: ComputeError(Owned("Failed to determine supertype of Datetime(Microseconds, None) and Time"))
```

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if this is a bug.

Tried to filter a series using a time range, and expected a filtered series for just those times.  Instead, I got a PanicException (list above).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to filter a DateTime with a Time. You need to cast to pl.Time before doing the is_between

```py
df.filter(
pl.col('date').cast(pl.Time).is_between(time(9, 30), time(14, 30))
)
┌─────────────────────┐
│ date                │
│ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 2023-02-07 10:00:00 │
│ 2023-02-07 10:30:00 │
│ 2023-02-07 11:00:00 │
│ 2023-02-07 11:30:00 │
│ 2023-02-07 12:00:00 │
│ 2023-02-07 12:30:00 │
│ 2023-02-07 13:00:00 │
│ 2023-02-07 13:30:00 │
│ 2023-02-07 14:00:00 │
└─────────────────────┘
```